# Is there a standard name for this infinite group?

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Consider the group of sequences
$$\{(a_1,a_2,\dots): a_i\in\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\}$$
where the group operation is component-wise addition. Is there a standard name for this group, such as $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\infty}$, $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$, or something similar? It is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ under addition, but I want to emphasize the additive group structure and not assign it any multiplicative structure.

EDIT: Silly me, it's not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$. See below.

Comment: I would call it $\prod_{\mathbb Z} \mathbf C_2$ or $\prod_{\mathbb Z} \mathbf (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$. But it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z[x]$ because there only a finite number of terms can be non-zero, this latter group I would denote $\bigoplus_{\mathbb Z} \mathbf C_2$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be standard to call this group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\mathbb{N}$ or $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\omega$, or perhaps $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  It has probably also been called $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^\infty$, but I would recommend avoiding that notation, as it often (possibly more often) refers to the subgroup of your group consisting of sequences which have only finitely many nonzero entries.  Incidentally, $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is *not* isomorphic to your group, rather it is isomorphic to this subgroup of sequences with finite support.  The full sequence space is isomorphic instead to (the underlying additive group of) the *power series* ring $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$.

Comment: Or, it is equal to $\mathrm(Hom)(\mathbb F_2[x],\mathbb F_2)$ where the homomorphisms are group homomorphism. They are dual vectors spaces over $\mathbb F_2$.